# Authoritative reference of double induction

Tags: reference-request, induction

In my recent work, I have used the following double induction:

Let $ P(n,m) $ be a proposition about $n,m\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$. To show $P(n,m)$ is true for all $n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ and all $m\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$, I did:

1. Prove $P(0,m)$ is true for all $m\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$. (I can show directly for all $m\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ is true, without induction on $m$).
2. Assume $P(n_0,m)$ is true for some $n_0\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ and all $m\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$, show that $P(n_0+1,m)$ is true for all $m\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$.

Then, conclude that $P(n,m)$ is true for all $n,m\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$.

In the beginning, I also cast doubt on the logic of my own proof. Thanks to the answer from Mario Carneiro at:

[Axiom of Double Induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1523367/axiom-of-double-induction)

that convince me a lot that my proof is right.

**My Question:**

Actually, I am not quite sure if this is a 'double induction' since I prove directly for any $m$ at inductive step instead of doing induction on it. Since I am a stranger to set theory so I really need an authoritative reference (i.e. books or papers) which clearly show this method with some simple examples of that. So that I can put my proof on my work. And, BTW, is there any term or special name for this kind of induction?

I really appreciate any help on that in advance.

Comment: Any textbook on Grobner bases (or rewrite systems) should include a good discussion of  various (term) orders on $\,\Bbb N^{\large k}$ that prove useful for induction / descent. This should prove enlightening.

Comment: This is not "double induction". This is just simple induction, where the statement you are proving has a "for all $m$" quantifier in it. You don't need any axioms for that. See, e.g., Remark 2.27 in [my *Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*, version of 4 October 2018](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2018-10-04) for a discussion (I don't think I ever do "proper" double induction in these notes).

Comment: Double induction, however, isn't much harder: It just means that inside the induction step (or the induction base), you prove an auxiliary statement by induction. Once again, you don't need any new axioms (or authoritative references) for that.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks, I will try to find it out.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks a lot for your note. I will read that.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction