# Is my induction proof correct?

Tags: solution-verification

**Prove:** *$\forall n,m\in \mathbb{N_{0}}:n+m\in \mathbb{N_{0}}$*. 
**Remark.** By $\mathbb{N_{0}}$ we mean $0\in \mathbb{N}$.

*Proof.* Let $n,m\in \mathbb{N_{0}.}$

Providing $m=n=0,$

\begin{align*}
n+m=n\tag*{because $n+0:=n$}
\end{align*}

Thus $n\in \mathbb{N_{0}}$ given that $n=0$.

Now, assume \begin{align*}\forall k,s\in \mathbb{N}: k+s\in \mathbb{N}\end{align*}

And notice that $(k+1),(s+1)\in \mathbb{N}$. So, in particular, $(k+1)+(s+1)\in \mathbb{N}.$ Therefore $\forall n,m\in \mathbb{N}:n+m\in \mathbb{N}$ by the principle of mathematical induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's okay to assume for $k$ and $s$ and show that it's true for $k+1$ and $s+1$. If you really want to use induction on two variables, then there's something called [double induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1523367/axiom-of-double-induction) which you need to use.

However, the proof can be done much more easily by using induction on one variable only.

Consider $m\in \mathbb{N}$.

**Base Case:** $m+1$ (or $0$ depending on which system you are using) belongs to $\mathbb{N}$ because by definition of $\mathbb{N}$ using [Peano's axioms](https://www.britannica.com/science/Peano-axioms), the successor of a element in $\mathbb{N}$ belongs to $\mathbb{N}$.

**Induction Case:** Let $m+k\in \mathbb{N}$. Then using the same argument as above, $m+k+1\in \mathbb{N}$.

This completes the proof.

Comment: I didn't even know that, cheers! Quick question: So in the induction hypothesis I would assume for instance $\forall k\in \mathbb{N}:k+s\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: So is "weak" induction only meant for one variable?

Comment: @HannyBoy Glad to help. Yes, you may assume it for all $k$, or alternatively (which I did) prove it for any general $k$ and argue that since the choice of $k$ was arbitrary, it holds for all $k$.

Comment: @HannyBoy Yes, the weak induction that we generally learn in school is useful for one variable only. If you want to extend it, just follow the link to double induction.

Comment: You're brilliant! Thanks again!

Comment: @HannyBoy Thanks :)