# What is an example of a statement equivalent to $\omega^{\omega}$-induction?

Tags: logic, set-theory, ordinals, foundations, ordinal-analysis

If $\alpha$ is a countable ordinal and $A$ is the set of natural numbers having well-ordering of type $\alpha$, **does this mean that $\alpha$-induction (transfinite induction up to $\alpha$) is equivalent to the Well-Ordering Principle on $A$?**

For example, if $A=\{0,2,4,6,\ldots,1,3,5,\ldots\}$ (i.e. $1$ is greater than any even number in the well-ordering), **what would be a statement about the elements of $A$ that would require induction past $\omega$? Would the following statement work?**

$$\exists\, n\in A\,\forall\,m\in A: (n>0)\wedge(n>\rm{S}\overset{m}{\cdots}\rm{S}0)$$

where $\rm{S}$$x$ denotes the successor of $x$ in $A$ (note, if $m=0$ then $\rm{S}\overset{m}{\cdots}\rm{S}0$ is $0$).

Finally, Goodstein's Theorem or the Consistency of PA are a well-kown results which are equivalent to $\varepsilon_{0}$-induction. **What is an example of a statement equivalent to $\omega^{\omega}$-induction?**

---

There is something wrong with my statement above. When $m$ is "odd" I cannot think of it as the number I am using to represent it, so the expression $\rm{S}\overset{m}{\cdots}\rm{S}0$ does not make sense.

How about simply the statement $\forall\,n\in A:0+n = n$?

Comment: “$m\atop\cdots$” doesn't make sense to me. Normally when you write something like “$17\atop\cdots$” you're looking at the audience and saying “just pretend I wrote 17 $S$es here”, which you can do because $SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS0$ is actually a term of the object language.  And when you write something like “$N\atop \cdots$” you're looking at the audience saying “just pretend we have some number $N$ in mind and I wrote that many $S$es.” But you can't do that with your $m$ here because it is a bound variable and doesn't have a value.I don't know what  “$\forall m:P(S{m\atop\cdots}0)$”  could mean.

Comment: Analogous to $\epsilon_0$ for PA, $\omega^\omega$ is the [proof-theoretic ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_analysis) for PRA, as well as some other systems.

Comment: PRA = [primitive recursive arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_arithmetic)

Comment: @MJD Yes, I realized it did not make sense for "odd" terms before you posted your comment and edited it. And precisely for the reason you mention. I was confusing the object for the symbol used to represent it. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Odd or even, it doesn't make sense for purely syntactic reasons.

Comment: Yes, as I said in a comment above, I was confusing the object for the symbol used to represent it. I am part of the audience. The statement does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove the question from the unanswered list I will mention the following ($\alpha$-induction means induction up to $\alpha$, also called induction of length $\alpha$):

The fairly common "double induction" is $\omega^{2}$-induction, and it can occur as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4646283/30229). Let's unpack that a bit more to formulate a version of double induction, or $\omega^{2}$-induction:

> If $P(i,j)$ is a doubly indexed family of statements, one for each $i\ge a$ and $j\ge b$ such that
>
> 1. $P(a,b)$ is true,
> 2. $\forall i\ge a$, $P(i,b)\Rightarrow P(i+1,b)$,
> 3. $\forall j\ge b$, we have $\forall i\ge a$, $P(i,j)\Rightarrow P(i,j+1)$,
>
> then $P(i,j)$ is true for all $i\ge a$ and $j\ge b$.

A simple example of use of $\omega^{2}$-induction is the proof of the statement

1. $\forall i,j\ge 1$, $(i + 1)\cdot j>i\cdot j$

Proving that the usual order relation $<$ on $\mathbb{N}$ is a linear ordering uses $\omega^{2}$-induction.

Another example is the proof that $\boldsymbol{\cdot}$ is commutative, where $\boldsymbol{\cdot}$ is simply multiplication defined on the natural numbers (i.e. as a function $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that $i\boldsymbol{\cdot}0=0$, and $i\boldsymbol{\cdot}S(j)=(i\boldsymbol{\cdot}j)+i$, where $S$ is the succesor function). It is worth illustarting the process in this case:

First, we show $0\boldsymbol{\cdot}i=0$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$. Next, we prove $i\boldsymbol{\cdot}j=j\boldsymbol{\cdot}i$ using induction on $i$. Later in the proof, we will be assuming $i\boldsymbol{\cdot}j=j\boldsymbol{\cdot}i$ for all $j\in\mathbb{N}$ and will be trying to show that $S(i)\boldsymbol{\cdot}j=j\boldsymbol{\cdot}S(i)$ for all $j\in\mathbb{N}$. In order to do this, we will have to use induction again, this time on $j$.

Additionally, the original proofs of the finite version of [Ramsey's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem) (see [Nes1995] below for the proof) and the [Hales-Jewett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hales%E2%80%93Jewett_theorem) theorem (original proof [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1963-106-02/S0002-9947-1963-0143712-1/S0002-9947-1963-0143712-1.pdf)) both use $\omega^{2}$-induction. It is important to note that this use is not essential, as it was later shown by Paul Erdős and Saharon Shelah, which used $\omega$-induction.

For more on double, or $\omega^{2}$-induction, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1523367/axiom-of-double-induction). It contains several interesting links.

As a final note on $\omega^{2}$-induction, note how the process essentially performs induction on one variable with another induction on the other variable inside the proof. This nested induction idea can be generalized to speak of $\omega^{n}$-induction for $n\ge 2$ in a relatively straightforward manner.

Regarding $\omega^{\omega}$-induction, lemma 3.6 of [Sim1988] shows that well orderedness of $\omega^{\omega}$ (i.e. $\omega^{\omega}$-induction) is equivalent over $\mathsf{RCA}_{0}$ to each of the following statements:

1. Dickson's Lemma - For each $m\in\mathbb{N}$, the $m$-fold Cartesian power $\mathbb{N}^{m}$ is [well quasiordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-quasi-ordering).
2. The Hilbert Basis Theorem - For all countable fields $K$ and all $m\in\mathbb{N}$, any ideal in the polynomial ring $K[x_{1},\ldots,x_{m}]$ is finitely generated.

The book **Subsystems of Second order Arithmetic**, 2nd. ed., by Stephen G. Simpson is an excellent resource containing a plethora of results whose ordinal strength (i.e. to what level of transfinite induction they are equivalent to) is precisely determined.

Another example of use of $\omega^{\omega}$-induction can be found in the usual proof via ordinals of the Weak Goodstein Theorem (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4884481/30229)). Moreover, with a straightforward modification, the usual proof produces, for $n\ge 2$, examples of $(\omega\uparrow\uparrow n)$-induction (where $\omega\uparrow\uparrow n= \underbrace{\omega^{\omega^{^{.^{.^{.^\omega}}}}}}_{n}$) This is achieved by modifying the base-bumping process involved in defining the weak Goodstein sequences by bumping additional exponents:

1. Bumping the base (call them level $0$ exponents if you may) and the exponents (level $1$) as well will yield $\omega^{{\omega}^{\omega}}$-induction in the usual proof.
2. Additionally bumping the exponents of the exponents (level $2$) will get us $(\omega\uparrow\uparrow 4)$-induction.

And so on. Stopping at bumping at level $n+1$ exponents will yield $(\omega\uparrow\uparrow n)$-induction.

It is worth noting that $(\omega\uparrow\uparrow n)$-induction is essential in each case. For example, the $\omega^{\omega}$-induction required by the Weak Goodstein Theorem cannot be reduced to $\omega^{n}$-induction for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (See [Cai2007 - p.390]: it is not provable within $\mathsf{PRA}$ or $\mathsf{I\Sigma}_{1}$, both of which have proof theoretic ordinal $\omega^{\omega}$. More generally, the level $n$ modified statement is not provable within $\mathsf{I\Sigma}_{n+1}$, whose proof theoretic ordinal is $\omega\uparrow\uparrow (n+1)$).

---

[Cai2007] *Caicedo, Andrés Eduardo*, [**Goodstein’s function**](https://eudml.org/doc/129620), Rev. Colomb. Mat. 41, No. 2, 381-391 (2007). [ZBL1156.03053](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1156.03053).

[Nes1995]  Nešetřil, J., **Ramsey Theory**, Handbook of Combinatorics, Vol. 1,2, Elsevier Sci. B. V., Amsterdam, 1995, pp. 1133-1142.

[Sim1988]  Simpson, S.G., *Ordinal Numbers and the Hilber Basis Theorem*, **The Journal of Symbolic Logic**, Vol. 53 (1988), pp. 961-974.